# Защита от рекламодателей блокирующих браузер

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Всем привет! Наверняка все знают о сайтах, которые блокирует браузер и его становится очень трудно закрыть, да ещё те требуют деньги. Хотелось бы, отлавливать такие сайты автоматически. Я так понимаю блокировка происходит с помощью бесконечного alert, confirm, beforeOnClose alert. Или блокируют браузер иначе? Полагаю, распознать такое невозможно обычным парсингом кодов с сайта, ибо их могут сильно обфусцировать. Значит необходима javascript машинка, которая будет исполнять скрипты? Если есть идеи и инструменты по исполнению js и анализу зовещих блокирующих функций - расскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: В современных браузерах нет возможности показывать блокирующие окна на window.onbeforeunload именно из-таких сайтов. Машинка  которая исполняет скрипты есть, называется браузер. Есть такие штуки как headless browsers именно для всякого робосерфинга. Самый популярный - называется PhantomJS

Comment: В общем тематика как мне кажется запоздала лет на пять, современные браузеры позволяют такую пакость быстро закрыть, показывая галочку на закрытие после энного-модального окна, я ничего не убиваемого юзером в пару кликов, давно не видел.

Comment: Согласен, что это устарело, но читал в свежей статье о тизерных сетях то что проблема до сих пор остаётся проблемой. Возможно остался способ блокировать браузер, за ответ спасибо, погляжу что за PhantomJS

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Я тоже заметил, что можно без проблем закрывать такие окна. Закрываем вопрос как "Не по теме" → "Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится"?

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, как обычно все зависит от браузера, недавно только проскакивала тема с бесконечным циклом который вешает хром, но который можно убить в ff

Comment: @Grundy, ну да, в любом случае способы есть, но они не так просто детектятся автоматически и быстро меняются, ибо вендоры дыры быстро закрывают.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, да не, оно _в принципе_ воспроизводится, только не в массовом порядке